# How do I get past the sunken bridge in The Pirates Of Dark Water?

Tags: the-pirates-of-dark-water

How do you get past the sunken bridge level in *The Pirates of Dark Water* on Sega Genesis? I've been stuck on this level for ages, and I can't get past it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have actually run into this issue also, and I beat the game after like 3 years. You need to go as far as you can in the level, and then go backwards until you get to the last guard tower. There you will be able to jump upwards and climb up onto a ledge to get across and finish the level.